# Как тестировать "меню" на компьютере?

Tags: unity3d

[image: Скриншот проблемы]

Вот такую картину я наблюдаю на компьютере. При билде и запуске на телефоне оно все соразмерно, но неудобно делать наугад, а потом для тестирования билдить проект и ставить на телефон.
Основа меню - такое же из официального урока юнити по меню

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На компьютере можно указать соотношение сторон и разрешение. Это можно сделать в верхней части окна на закладке Game, там где на скриншоте написано "3:2 landscape"

Comment: Cпасибо, помогло WXGA Landscape (1280x800). А вот в PlayScene нужно возвращать 3:2 Landscape 0_о

Comment: Возможно, есть еще способ. При выборе `Canvas` среди GameObject, справа появляются настройки для него. И там есть `Canvas Scaler Script`, в котором можно указать пиксели или разрешение. Я не тестировал, как это работает, просто заметил такую штуку и предположил, что оно тоже может помочь